# Unable to Install Python on Computer

Tags: windows-10, installation, python

I am trying to install python 3.7.4 on my computer, but I had previously installed python on a different drive. Now when I try to install python it does not give me an install option in the installer.
The options I have (Modify, Repair, Uninstall) that all point to a drive that is not in my computer. Whenever I attempt to run any of the options they all fail since they can't find the drive, and I can't find a way to switch drives. The Modify option shows an install location, but the box is greyed out so it can't be changed.
Is there a way of changing the install location back to my C drive?

Comment: You might want to have a look this [article on removing software](https://www.howtogeek.com/314734/how-to-manually-remove-programs-from-the-windows-uninstall-program-list/), particular the bit about using CCleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The path of the installation is saved in the Windows registry. You can try the following:

- Start Run and type regedit (It will open registry Editor)
- Go to the folder "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.6" from the tree on left hand side (or whichever version you have).
- The following folders have the python path saved: Idle, InstallPath, PythonPath (maybe different in your system). In all the registry entries, modify the path in "Value data" to the new path where you would like to have python (right click -> Modify on the Name entry as shown in the figure in the link below).

[Regedit entry for Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bvE7.png)

E.g. modify the entry from D:\Python\Python36\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw to C:\Users.....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw

- Then if you run the installer again, you should be able to modify or repair the python installation.

It worked for me, I could repair my installation on another drive with this method. Please tell if it works for you.